# Selectively iterating over a list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I have a list of objects in Scheme. Each object in turn is a list itself. I am using the `map` function to iterate over all the elements of the list and apply a function to them. However, I want to apply that function only if the element of the list satisfies some criteria. In `C++` that would be something like this:

```cpp
for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
{
    if(criteria(list[n]))
    //do something
}
```

How do I do this in Scheme? Right now, I am using the map function like this:

```
(map create-evaluation-link parse)
```

Where `create-evaluation-link` is a function and `parse` is the list.

Comment: Using `for` loops is often an indicator of imperative-style code. There may be a way to do things more functionally depending on what you're attempting to do. That said, Racket has `for` loops and list comprehensions, though that's obviously a different dialect.

Comment: When you say you want to apply that function only to lists satisfying some criterion, are you using map for its side-effects or its value? I'm wondering if you want to preserve the value of the non-matching lists in the the returned list, or if you are just running all of this for its side-effect. For example, if your `criteria` is `(lambda (l) (even? (length l)))`, your input list is `((3 2 1) (2 1) (4 3 2 1))`, do you want to be able to pass a function like `car` and get `(2 4)` as the result, or `((3 2 1) 2 4)`, or pass a procedure which has some side effect and gets run on the latter two?

Comment: I am using map for its value, not for the side effect. I just want to apply `create-evaluation-link` to the elements. Nothing more. In your example, I would want to apply my function only to `(2 1)` and `(4 3 2 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the approach you're taking, just map a function that checks whether the item meets the criteria:

```
(map (lambda (x)
       (if (criteria? x)
           (create-evaluation-link x)))
      parse)
```

However, as others have noted in the comments, using **map** to do imperative work may be a place where some other approach might be more natural in Scheme.  For instance, you might first filter out the values that don't meet the criteria, and then map create-evaluation-link over that to get a list of evaluation-links.

```
(map create-evaluation-link (filter criteria? parse))
```

Comment: I didn't use your code. Instead I used a filter. I marked your answer as accepted since you suggested me to use a filter.
If you want, you could edit the code in your answer to include a filter.